# Can not get the special charcter from query string value using PHP

Tags: php, get

I need one help. I need to fetch all data from query string using PHP but some special charcters like (`i.e-+,- etc`) are not coming. I am explaining my code below.

```
http://localhost/test/getmethod.php?name=Goro + Gun
```

Here I need to get the value assign to `name` using the below code.

```
<?php
$name=$_GET['name'];
echo $name;
?>
```

Here I am getting the output like `Goro Gun` but I need the original value `i.e-Goro + Gun` .Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: `Goro Gun` is the exact value in browser URL you view `Goro+Gun` as space is replaced by "+". To get the same you can use urlencode()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@subhra try this for this case name=Goro + Gun:

```
<?php
$nameArr = explode('=', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$name = str_replace("%20", " ", $nameArr[1]);
echo $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] - this will return you full query string
```

Comment: By adding like you its throwing error.`Notice: Undefined index: name`.I did like this `$name=$_SERVER['name'];`.

Comment: no no, $_SERVER['name'] will not work, I mean you will get all url parameters as a string if you echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Comment: if I will have many values like this `http://localhost/test/getmethod.php?name=Goro + Gun&cid=20` and I need to get each value individually. In that case what will happen.

Comment: see what it returned `name=Goro%20+%20Gun`. its not like exact value %20 also taking in case of space.

Comment: So, you need to replace + sign with any other special character like * and then get and replace * with + sign

Comment: as per your above info if you need + sign as it is in variable(name) value, or it's already there before passing it to url as parameter then you need to encode it fist `urlencode("Goro + Gun")` then you can decode it using `urldecode()`